# Can't start OSGI bundle in Apache ServiceMix

Tags: java, osgi, osgi-bundle, apache-servicemix

I want create `OSGI` bundle. I createad a simple class:

```
public class Activator implements BundleActivator {
public void start(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("::::START MAIL BUNDLE::::");
}

public void stop(BundleContext bundleContext) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("::::STOP MAIL BUNDLE::::");
}
}
```

My `pom.xml`:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.0</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>osgi-bundle</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>bundle</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <instructions>
                            <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                            <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                            <Import-Package>
                                *;resolution:=optional
                            </Import-Package>
                        </instructions>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

I using `Service Mix`. I add `org.osgi.core-6.0.0.jar` and my jar in target folder. My bundle is active, but I don't see my message when start/stop bundle in `karaf` console. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set `<Bundle-Activator>your.package.name.Activator</Bundle-Activator>` in the maven-bundle-config. 
Please also note to never deploy org.osgi.core or org.osgi.componendium. The core packages are deployed by the OSGi framework and compendium by the individual spec impls.